# Kendo Ui Model Binding 3 level Object

Tags: c#, model, kendo-ui

What I want to do is create a grid, and when you click on it opens up a detail grid for the user to choose. I created them like this

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.items).Name("Access")
 .Columns(columns =>
 {
  columns.Bound("ProjId").Width(220).Title("Project #");       
  })       
  .ClientDetailTemplateId("detailTemplateId")  
  .Selectable()  
  .Events(events => events.DetailInit("initDetailGrid"))                                        
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
  .Ajax()
  .ServerOperation(false)                
  )
)

<script id="detailTemplateId" type="text/kendo-tmpl">   

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.items.subItems).Name("detailGrid")
.Columns(columns => columns.Bound("itemsName").Title("Select"))   
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                        .Ajax()
                        .ServerOperation(false)
                        )
.ToClientTemplate()
)
</script>
```

The model is created like this

```
 public class ItemModel
{        
    public List<myItems> items; 

    public ItemModel()
    {           
        items = new List<myItems>();
    }
}
```

the myItems class is defined elsewhere, and inside the myItems class is a sub class which is the subItems that I am trying to get

```
public class myItems
{
    public int ProjId;
    public List<otherItems> subItems; 

    public myItems(){
        subItems =  new List<otherItems>();
    }
    public class otherItems()
    {           
        public String itemsName;
        public int itemId
    }
}
```

but when I try to bind it here `@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.items.subItems).Name("detailGrid")` 
says that it cannot resolve symbol? Am I doing it the right way? or do I have to bing it to items, then get the values in inside the columns using the columns template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically when dealing with server-bound Grids you should use **DetailTemplate** instead of **DetailTemplateID**

Here is an example:

```
@model IEnumerable<Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Product>

@helper ThirdLevelHelper(Kendo.Mvc.Examples.Models.Product x)
{

      @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
        .Name("Grid"+Guid.NewGuid())
        .Columns(columns => {
            columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID).Groupable(false);
            columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
            columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice);
            columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock);
        })
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()
        .Scrollable() 
        .Filterable()
        .Groupable()
    )
}

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock);
    })
    .DetailTemplate(@<text>
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)    
    .Name("Grid"+item.ProductID)
    .Columns(columns => {
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID).Groupable(false);
        columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice);
        columns.Bound(p => p.UnitsInStock);
    })
    .DetailTemplate(x=>ThirdLevelHelper(x))
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable() 
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
)
</text>)
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable() 
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
)
```

Nitice that for the 3rd level of the hierarchy you will have to use helper method, because Razor does not allow such nesting @ operators.

ALso you have to find a way and guarantee that the name of each Grid widget down the hierarchy is unique. This is usually done by appening sufix.

Also take a closer look and see how context is propagated down to the nested Grids, by passing the current item, it is slightly different when using a helper.